# using F# XMLProvider for large nested xml file

Tags: linq, f#

I have a large deeply nested xml file, over 200MB. I have written a streaming function in c# using linq to xml. But knowing about f# type provider I am tempted to use the XMLTypeProvider but it may load the entire xml into memory. Is there any way to optimize it to lazy load in the provider and get the benefit of dot. Thanks

Comment: A similar question was asked a few hours after this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37142356/126014 Is this homework?

Comment: you should be suprised how rapidly the type providers are gaining popularity