# Type provider and big XML file

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers

I am wondering what are the good practices in using type provider in F#,

I have an XML file (25Mo+), I thought it will not be an issue but my Visual Studio is suffering a lot loll. What is usually the good practice, to define a complete template of the XML with the minimum of data and Load the content later ?

And if we load a big file with optional node, the type will be inferred by the most complete one ?

Thanks

Comment: With an XML file that large, you might be better off not using any tool that loads the entire thing into memory.  `XmlReader` might be the way to go, as it allows you to selectively load only the parts of the document you actually need at any given time.

Comment: Thanks @JoelMueller I knew they was a size limitation, but I didn't thought that a 25 MO would be already too big :(

Comment: A similar question was asked a few hours before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37135965/126014 Is this homework?

Comment: lol @MarkSeemann the day where typeprovider will be a homework subject will be a great day :)

Comment: @rad it's not that I think the type provider can't handle it, it's just that it's seldom a good idea to load a 25 MB file into memory unless you need to use all the data in the file at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The `XmlProvider` type provider is based on `XDocument` (LINQ to XML), so it always needs to read the file into memory. However, there may be some additional overhead caused by the schema inference, which you can avoid. So, if LINQ to XML can read 25MB file (I'm not sure, try using `XDocument.Load` on the file), then you would be able to use the type provider.

Assuming `big.xml` is your big file, you can try deleting some of the elements from the file (so that all structure is there, but it is smaller) and creating `small.xml`. Then you can use:

```
type X = XmlProvider<"small.xml">
let data = X.Load("big.xml")
```

This will only run schema inference on the smaller file (which runs in background in Visual Studio) and then it attempts to read the bigger file using LINQ to XML. This just reads the file, so if LINQ to XML can read 25MB file, this will work.

Ideally, we would have some variation on the type provider that works over `XmlReader` or something like that - this could reuse some of F# Data infrastructure, but it would still be a lot of work (open an [issue at F# Data](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data) is you're interested in contributing!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are (hopefully temporarily) huge perf issues with XMLProvider.
https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/975

If someone would merge my PR of #983 or #976 they would be fixed. In a meanwhile you can fork and try a copy of my repo at https://github.com/Thorium/FSharp.Data